# unknown exception error in php

Tags: php

i wanna catch all exceptions thrown in a script and then check if they have a error code 23000.

if they don't i want to rethrow the exception.

here is my code:

```
function myException($exception) {
    /*** If it is a Doctrine Connection Mysql Duplication Exception ***/
    if(get_class($exception) === 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' && $exception->getCode() === 23000) {
         echo "Duplicate entry";
    } else {
         throw $exception;
    }
}

set_exception_handler('myException');

$contact = new Contact();
$contact->email = 'peter';
$contact->save();
```

but i get this error message and i dont know what it means:

```
Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

i want to be able to rethrow the original error message if it has not the error code 23000.

even when i deleted the check errorcode i still get the same message:

```
function myException($exception) {
    throw $exception;
}

set_exception_handler('myException');

$contact = new Contact();
$contact->email = 'peter';
$contact->save();
```

how could i solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the exception handler for this.

The exception handler is only the "last resort" to handle *uncaught* exceptions.

You can't throw a new exception within it - it would lead to an infinite loop.

The regular way to handle exceptions is using a `try... catch {}` block:

```
try
 {
  $contact->save();
 }
catch (Exception $exception)
 {
  if(get_class($exception) === 'Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception' 
     && $exception->getCode() === 23000) {
         echo "Duplicate entry";
    } else {
         throw $exception; // throw it on if it's not a doctrine exception
                           // (if that's what you want)
    }

 }
```

I know this looks way more messy than the way you do it. That's why I'm not really fond of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure but try this code

```
function myException($exception) {
    restore_exception_handler();
    throw $exception;
}
//you can set here another exception handler that will be restored.
//or your exception will be thrown to standard handler
//set_exception_handler('myException2');

set_exception_handler('myException');

$contact = new Contact();
$contact->email = 'peter';
$contact->save();
```