# exceptions thrown terminate the script?

Tags: php

i wonder if exceptions that are thrown in php will terminate the script in php?

cause when i save an entry that is already created in doctrine it throws an exception.

i catch the exception and ignore it (so that the user won't see it) but the script seems to be terminated.

is there a way to catch the exception and keep the script alive?

thanks

Comment: Yes, I showed how to do that in your last question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796863/unknown-exception-error-in-php/2796903#2796903

Comment: Yes the exception will terminate the script. You might be throwing another exception from your catch block or another error might be causing the script to terminate. Debug my friend! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the function call(s) that may throw an exception in a `try...catch` block.

```
class EvilException extends Exception {}
class BadException extends Exception {}

function someMethodThatMayThrowException() {
   ...
   ...
   throw new EvilException( "I am an evil exception. HAHAHAHA" );
}
try {

someMethodThatMayThrowException();

} catch( BadException $e ) {
  //deal with BadException here...
} catch( EvilException $e ) {
   //deal with EvilException here...
   throw new Exception( "will be caught in next catch block" );
} catch( Exception $e ) {
   echo $e->getMessage(); //echoes the string: "will be caught in next catch block"
}
```

If you catch the exception(s), the script will not terminate. If a thrown exception does not have a `catch` block to jump into, the aforementioned will happen.

Comment: +1 you can also throw the exception again in the `catch` block to pass it on.